# How to MongoDB monitoring with Zabbix

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, monitor, zabbix

I using the Zabbix Server: 5.0.14 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 and Zabbix Agent: 5.4.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.
Ubuntu 18.04 install MongoDB 4.4.7.

Zabbix Server can monitor OS Ubuntu 18.04 but the MongoDB monitor data is doesn't have anymore.
I am using Template DB MongoDB node by Zabbix Agent 2 or Template DB MongoDB cluster by Zabbix Agent 2 is still not working.
I attacked some screenshot config.
Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the version of ZABBIX server to 5.4, and then modify the macro configuration. The default `{$MONGODB.CONNSTRING}` of ZABBIX's own template is `TCP: localhost: 27017`, which needs to be modified to the IP and port of mongodb you want to monitor.